# Which Mammoth came first: the animal or the description?

Tags: etymology, british-english

I thought to describe something in my writing as *Mammoth*, and that got me thinking:

- was the word originally used to describe the animal *Mammoth*, and adapted to describe anything that is colossally large?
- was the word originally used to describe something large, and upon discovering the animal *Mammoth* attributed to it because of its large size?

---

If it is the former, then where did the word originate from? Or did they just assign a random name to an unknown creature?

Comment: The answer can be found in one of the standard references for this site http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mammoth (the animal-1706, large in size-1802). OED has the animal back to 1698. List of commonly-available references, dictionaries and suchlike can be found here http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2574/71783

Comment: The animal **obviously** came first. By a couple hundred thousand years. ;)

Comment: Your edit makes this a decent question - it would be good to edit your question so that you explain you now know that the noun was before the adjective, but you want to know how the English word _Mammoth_ came about - OED does not have a definitive origin but I suspect _behemoth_ might be involved, the only two words in OED ending in -moth (that aren't moths) are _behemoth_ and _mammoth_.

Comment: @Frank & OP: Homework! :)

Comment: See also: "The shift of use from a prehistoric mammoth (noun) to something of mammoth proportions (adjective), for example, isn’t unusual and is of a type well recorded elsewhere in the language." **OED Word Stories** http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/word-stories/mammoth/

Comment: @Frank: The online OED has a pretty convincing case that it came from the Russian: *mamant*, which has a variant *mamut*, possibly explaining the lack of an 'n'. The 'th' instead of the 't' at the end appeared possibly because it came to English through German or Dutch, where it was possibly influenced by *behemoth*. The OED's first citation: 1618   R. James *Dictionariolum Russico-Anglicum*   Maimanto, as they say a sea elephant, which is never seene, but accordinge to the Samγites he workes himself under grownde and so they finde his teeth or hornes or bones in Pechore and Nova Zemla.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, the online OED has changed it's mind about the origin, and that's not a general-reference site, so could actually provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online OED says it comes from the Russian word *mamant* (now *mamont*). Their first citation is:

> 1618 R. James *Dictionariolum Russico-Anglicum* ... *Maimanto,* as they say a sea elephant, which is never seene, but accordinge to the Samγites he workes himself under grownde and so they finde his teeth or hornes or bones in Pechore and Nova Zemla.

This leaves several questions: why is the ending *-th* instead of *-nt*? And where did the Russian word come from in the first place.

The 'th' apparently appeared because it came to English through German (or maybe Dutch), where the 't' was changed into a 'th'. At the time, 't' and 'th' stood for the same /t/ sound in German. (Since then, 'th' has vanished from German because of spelling reform.) The OED speculates that the *-moth* ending was used in analogy with the German word *Behemoth* (now *Behemot*), a Biblical animal which at times has been depicted as an elephant.

Why did the 'n' vanish? The OED has discovered a Russian variant *mamut* in 19th century dictionaries, but this may just be a transliteration of the French word *mammouth*. Alternatively, *mamant* may have changed to *Mammoth* in German in analogy with *Behemoth*.

And where did the word *mamant* come from in Russian in the first place? The OED  thinks it might have come from Old Vogul **mēmoŋt,* meaning earth-horn. But this seems to be based on the idea that if you put the words for *earth* and *horn* together, you get **mēmoŋt,* and not on any strong evidence. The current word for *mammoth* in Vogul is *mā-xar* or ‘earth-stag’. And Vogul is spoken in Siberia, where you find buried mammoth bones.

Comment: +1 And oddly enough the species name for Mastodons is _mammut_.